# Cocos2d: Solid color rectangular sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I must be missing something!

I want to create a solid rectangular CCSprite with a background color initialized to a particular RGB value.  I have looked all over the docs and can't find anything.

Is there a way to initialize the background of CCSprite to a specific color?
I don't want to have to include a solid color PNG for each colors that I will need.

Help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CCSprite` has a `color` property of type `ccColor3B`:

```
- (ccColor3B) color [read, assign]
RGB colors: conforms to CCRGBAProtocol protocol    

Definition at line 145 of file CCSprite.h.
```

Source: [CCSprite](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_sprite.html#ab7c1fe8d2419d19873095f2070d758f5) reference.

You can easily construct a ccColor3B struct using `ccc3()`:

```
ccc3(const GLubyte r, const GLubyte g, const GLubyte b)
```

Reference: [ccColor3B](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/structcc_color3_b.html) reference.

Comment: Justin,  thanks that was what I was doing ... the additional trick of course is setting the textureRect properly!!!

Answer (score 21):

Do it with code! if you don't want to mess with image files, here's your method:

```
- (CCSprite*)blankSpriteWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite node];
    GLubyte *buffer = malloc(sizeof(GLubyte)*4);
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {buffer[i]=255;}
    CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithData:buffer pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB5A1 pixelsWide:1 pixelsHigh:1 contentSize:size];
    [sprite setTexture:tex];
    [sprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    free(buffer);
    return sprite;
}
```

Then you can set your color, size and opacity as needed. ;)

Comment: For those of use working with the mutated counter part (that being cocos2d-x): https://gist.github.com/Mazyod/208e5fb2d7a56290a261

Answer (score 5):

I found answer at [cocos2d cookbook](http://cocos2dcookbook.com/).  The following code is derived from that book's chap 1, which is free for preview.

```
-(CCSprite *) rectangleSpriteWithSize:(CGSize)cgsize color:(ccColor3B) c
{
    CCSprite *sg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blank.png"];  
    [sg setTextureRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, cgsize.width, cgsize.height)];
    sg.color = c;   
    return sg;  
}
```

Yes, this still requires an external image file.  But with this 1x1 tiny 'blank.png', you can generate solid-color rectangle sprites with arbitrary size and color.

Answer (score 3):

I never got CCSprite to work like that. I just use CCLayerColor.

```
CCLayerColor* layercolorHalftransparentred = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(255, 0, 0, 128)];
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this question (like me); the code from Matjan doesn't seem to work anymore on cocos 2d 3.x. See below for an altered version that works for me:

```
+ (CCSprite*)blankSpriteWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    GLubyte *buffer = malloc(sizeof(GLubyte)*4);
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {buffer[i]=255;}
    CCTexture *tex = [[CCTexture alloc] initWithData:buffer pixelFormat:CCTexturePixelFormat_RGBA8888 pixelsWide:1 pixelsHigh:1 contentSizeInPixels:size contentScale:1];
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex rect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    free(buffer);
    return sprite;
}
```